# What's the correct term for ping (connection latency) in Standard Chinese/Cantonese?

Tags: translation, mandarin, cantonese

How would you say something like "I'm lagging again, my ping is spiking to 500(ms)" in Putonghua and Cantonese (in the context of online games)? I've heard someone say "網又卡了！" before, but I'm not entirely sure how common that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in putonghua，We say "网又卡了， 我ping都500了， 卡死了（damn lagging）， 你卡不？小王怎么一点都不卡呢？”

“Ping” is totally acceptable in Putonghua， just like “windows，NPC，BOSS”， all game players know it， or you can use "延迟”， “我延迟有500了” 。

Comment: Thank you for the response.
Follow up question: how would you say "What's your ping at right now?" without using the English word "ping"? Something like "你的延遲現在多少？" doesn't sound very natural to me (not even sure if that was grammatically correct).

Comment: @wang_xiao_ming Right, not very natural, people sometimes ask "你(的)延迟是多少？” “现在” is not necessary, "的" is omitted,or "你那延迟是多少？", if you want to add "现在", it can be "你（那）现在（是）多少延迟？"

Comment: @wang_xiao_ming BTW, I can not find a way to avoid these loaned words, I don't know how to say "NPC" or "BOSS" in Chinese. And I heard some people say "bug" "Bee U Gee", "那人用Bee U GEE"(That guy make use of bug). This is a interesting question.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know there weren't any Chinese translations for these terms.
Would "錯誤" be the appropriate translation for bug? I see it used for software from time to time, but I wouldn't think it works in your example as a replacement for "bug".

Answer (score 4):

Some technical terms do not have formal translation or still used in English form for the sake of convenience.

'Ping' is one of such example, alternatively you can use latency in Chinese '延迟'.

It would be more appropriate to use 'ping'  among IT guys and use latency '延迟' for non-IT users. However, in Cantonese especially among people from Hong Kong, it's advised to use English when referring to technical terms as the translation can be very different from Mandarin, unless you are very sure of the correct translation.